# using datatables.net on materialize design in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, datatables, material-design

hello i need to display this table that should be using the datatables.net plugin. i have already localized the plugin so in my code here is how i did it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('datatable/datatables.min.css') }}"/>
<script src="{{ asset('datatable/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // alert('boom');
        $('#detailTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

and my table

```
<table id="detailTable" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>System User ID</td>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Role</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach($usrs as $list)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $list->sid }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->role }}</td>
                <td>                  
                    <a href="{{URL::route('upnsau', array($list->sid))}}">
                         <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i> Edit Details
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

but the problem is it does not work the way it should be it just shows the table like this
[image]

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JQuery library in order for DataTables to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate version of jQuery to your view template. This is jQuery v3.0.0's link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```